# Get pictures from several links download and rename them (using Excel)

Tags: excel, vba

I have in A2 a text with a name. and in b2, c2, d2, e2, f2 I have links with pictures. I would like to download all the links and rename them with the name of A2 but adding to the file name _01, _02, _03, _04, _05 depending if the picture is from b2, c2, etc.

I have made a picture for explaining it better.
http://oi57.tinypic.com/119cx6v.jpg

There are more than one row, so after downloading one row it would have to keep downloading the others.

I have found the following code in another post, it is similar but not exactly what I need to do. Please any help would be appreciate it.

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, _
ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Dim Ret As Long

'~~> This is where the images will be saved. Change as applicable
Const FolderName As String = "C:\pato\"

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim strPath As String

    '~~> Name of the sheet which has the list
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LastRow '<~~ 2 because row 1 has headers
        strPath = FolderName & ws.Range("A" & i).Value & ".jpg"

        Ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, ws.Range("B" & i).Value, strPath, 0, 0)

        If Ret = 0 Then
            ws.Range("C" & i).Value = "File successfully downloaded"
        Else
            ws.Range("C" & i).Value = "Unable to download the file"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim c as Range, n as Long

    '~~> Name of the sheet which has the list
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LastRow '<~~ 2 because row 1 has headers

        n = 1
        Set c = ws.Range("B" & i)
        Do While Len(c.value) > 0 'loop while have a URL
            strPath = FolderName & ws.Range("A" & i).Value & _
                      "_" & Right("00" & n, 2) & ".jpg"

            Ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, c.Value, strPath, 0, 0)

            c.interior.color = IIf(Ret=0, vbGreen, vbRed) 'success?

            Set c = c.offset(0, 1) 'next cell to right
            n = n + 1
        Loop

    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! It worked flawlessly. I tried to vote but still can't vote because I don't have enough reputation. When I can I will come back to vote.